# Why does requiresSecure() cause redirect loop in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, heroku, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot v1.1.9.RELEASE and I deploy my app to Heroku.  I have just added an SSL certificate and it works fine, if I manually change the URL to HTTPS.

The problem is that after login, Spring Security switches back to HTTP.   I've read-up on this and found that adding the following forces HTTPS for all requests which sounds like exactly what I want:

```
.and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
```

However, when I try this, I get a redirect loop error. I don't understand why the server would constantly redirect.  I want every request to be HTTPS.  So the above code tells the server to redirect to HTTPS if the request is HTTP which seems to work.  But then it retries the redirect over and over.  Does anyone know why it does this?  The logs don't seem to be providing any insight into the behaviour.

Note: I also read somewhere that port-mapping may be the culprit but the suggested solution was to set a port mapping of 80 to 443 which as far as I know is the default setting.  I tried it anyway and it made no difference.

Comment: where you able to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that the HTTPS connection is not terminated at the servlet container and the container is unable to differentiate between connections which are over HTTPS or HTTP.

Check whether the [isSecure](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure%28%29) method on `HttpServletRequest` returns true when you make a request over HTTPS. If it doesn't then you need to find some way of configuring a Heroku application to allow the container to tell the difference. Most likely the router will set a header such as `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` which the container can be configured to make use of. You can do this in tomcat using the [`RemoteIpValve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html) but I don't know how much control you have over this in Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot the usage of the [Forwarded-Headers (RFC 7239)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239) can be activated in `application.properties`:

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=native
```

Reference: [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server)